# Encoding NSData into string containing only numbers and decoding back

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, decode

Base64 uses lower and uppercase alphabet and also some special characters

Base32 is better, but still uses also alphabet characters (the output is larger than base64 of course)

**How to encode a NSData into a number-only NSString?**

As i can transmit only number characters '0'-'9'

Comment: Base 10 or less is what you need.

Comment: BTW - Why such a limit?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I can transmit only number characters '0'-'9'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

1. `NSData` has methods to tell you how many bytes it represents and to provide a pointer to these bytes.
2. A byte is just an integer type in (Objective-)C, as an unsigned value it represents decimal 0 to 255
3. The string formatting methods can format an integer to a fixed number of digits using leading zeros, e.g. 004.

HTH